# How to populate ViewPager with strings from ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-viewpager

I have a list of items that each has their own `ArrayList<String>`. When an item is clicked, the ViewPager activity is opened. I want each string to fill up an entire view in ViewPager, so that the user can swipe through each of these strings as pages.

1. Is ViewPager the best way to go about doing this?
2. If so, how can I populate it with the contents of the `ArrayList<String>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use a `ViewPager`. To use it you need to supply a `PagerAdapter`. In your subclass of PagerAdapter, just have your `instatiateItem` override create a TextView (either programmatically, or by inflating a layout with a TextView) and set the text to the String at the position in the array corresponding to the `position` parameter of instantiateItem. Something like this

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem (ViewGroup container, int position) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
    tv.setText(mList.get(position));
    return tv;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Did you mean `container.getContext()`? I get an error with the getContext() inside TextView.

Comment: You are right... The adapter doesn't have a context so you will have to pass it by a setter method or constructor argument, the same way you pass in the list.

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing, and it's working well (although I still have to fix a few bugs in my PagerAdapter).